# Unable to log into my local Azure Mobile Service

Tags: .net, azure, azure-mobile-services

I feel kinda silly for asking this, but I can't seem to figure it out, despite the fact it's probably simple. I'm building a UWP app, with an Azure DB + Azure Mobile Service. I've recently tried adding authentication to the app, following [this tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-get-started-custom-authentication/). Though when I come to the point where I debug the Service, locally, and I try to log-in, I simply can't.

I've gone to the Azure management portal and copy/pasted the Application Key, the one I see when I click on 'Manage keys' at the bottom. I copied the key and pasted it into the password field, I get as a prompt, but I can't login. I'm certain I'm copying the Application key of the right mobile service. I've tried regenerating a new key, but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For local testing, ensure that you have your **MS_ApplicationKey** key defined in your local web.config app settings.

Comment: I do, but that one says 'Overriden by portal settings'

Comment: Yes, when deployed to Azure any value in this setting will be overridden by the one defined in your portal settings. For local debugging you just need to ensure you have a value set. So you can set any key value you wish there - copy the one from the portal, or use a different value. Just ensure you enter the same value in the login prompt when testing.

Comment: Aah right, that sort of makes sense, I suppose. So it was just `Overridden by portal settings` as a password, locally at least. Thanks a lot!